# Difference (in decimals) in the area before and after union

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area, arcgis-10.4, union

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1

**DATA**

I have two layers

- 5_catchments: polygon shapefile for 5 catchments
- nloss_clip_final.shp: polygon shapefile for Nloss

You can find and download the data from [**this link**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w3x6fl7p09hbvra/AACQsBw0rEQBiud7Z2JLwf1ya?dl=0).

I want to get the attributes of the two layers into one layer. I can do this using `intersect` or `union`. I used `union` to do so.

After using union, I exported the attribute table as .txt file and imported it into R to check the total area for the 5 catchments. I found difference in decimals of the total area in km2

Area (in km2) of 5 catchments before union

[image]

Area (in km2) of 5 catchments after union

[image]

Although the difference in the area (in km2) of the 5 catchments, before and after union, is in decimals (mainly in the most downstream catchment `Rangitikei_McKelvies` where the difference is around 0.047 km2), I wonder why there is a difference? Is it a rounding issue? or something else.

**UPDATE**

All the input and output layers are in NZGD2000 (New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000). Resolution and tolerance values are below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the exact command you used (it exists in the geoprocessing log).  It's highly likely that you specified a tolerance value which resulted in slight change to the geometries on overlay.

Comment: @Vince

I left XY tolerance empty in the Union without assigning any value

Comment: The `Union` command, of course.  Using default values is nearly always a mistake.

Comment: @Vince
Thanks. Which XY tolerance value you suggest?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify ***all*** your coordinate reference parameters, especially precision and tolerance values, in each of the input and output feature classes.